# Create a 'close/exit' option for a child frame that is created using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I have created a script using tkinter, that brings up a child frame when you press a button. The  frame occupies the full screen size on my mac laptop. Now I need to create an option to exit/ or close this new frame. What is the best option to do that?

-Thanks

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
class App(Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.apple = Button(self,
                     text="Apple", command=self.write_apple)
    self.apple.pack(side=LEFT)

def write_apple(self):
    self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=80)
    t = Toplevel(self)
    t.overrideredirect(True)
    t.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    l = Label(t, text="This is a green apple.",font=self.customFont)
    l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = App(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no best way, you need to use the way that is best suited to your program. You will need the `pack_forget()` at some point though.

Comment: Child **Frame** or child **Toplevel**? Terminology is important.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just allow normal window decorations? Why are you using `overrideredirect`?

Comment: I agree with @Bryan Oakley, if you don't use `overrideredirect` the close button or command W on mac will work fine.  And I have noticed all kinds of weird behaviour with `overrideredirect` especially on mac.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the override redirect and I'm now able to close the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution handles the case that multiple instances of `Toplevel` are created:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.apple = Button(self,
                            text="Apple", command=self.write_apple)
        self.apple.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.top_dict = dict()

    def destroy_top(self, event):
        # event.widget is the instance of Label that was clicked
        # Get the instance of Toplevel
        top = self.top_dict[event.widget]
        # Destroy the instance of Toplevel
        top.destroy()
        # Remove the instance of Toplevel from the list
        del self.top_dict[event.widget]

    def write_apple(self):
        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=80)
        # Create an instance of Toplevel
        top = Toplevel(self)
        top.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
        label = Label(top, text="This is a green apple.",font=self.customFont)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        # Bind the destroy_top method to the mouse-button-1 click
        label.bind('<Button-1>', self.destroy_top)
        # Save the instance of Toplevel using the label as the key
        self.top_dict[label] = top

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = App(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

NOTE: As @Bryan Oakley noted, removing the call to `overrideredirect` adds window decorations to the instance of `Toplevel`.

Comment: your answer would be better if you described what you changed. Otherwise the reader has to compare your code to the original line-by-line.

Comment: This fails if multiple tops are opened at once, only the last one can be closed and the others are stuck